# Microsoft Project bar connected to customized start-finish

Tags: microsoft-project

I am using MS Project to plan and track manufacturing schedules.

For this I have created 3 custom fields:

"Units" (Numbers1), which are the number of parts to be manufactured.
"Duration per Unit" (Duration1), These are typed in manually
"Total Duration" (Duration2), which is calculated by using Formula: [Numbers1]*[Duration1]
I managed to create two new columns (Start1 and Finish1) and I can even create an corresponding bar. 
BUT: the project looks at the standard "Start" and "Finish" and calculates around my manually created Start1 and Finish1. How can I let Project look at my new Start1 and Finish1 only?
Thanks for helping!!!
Matthias from DK

Answer (score 0):

The **Start1** and **Finish1** fields are for information only. If the tasks are in auto-schedule mode and are linked together, then the task **Duration** field is driving the **Start** and **Finish** dates. In that case you can select and copy the calculated **Duration1** field and paste in on top of the **Duration** field.

Notes:

- Remove all filters and hide Summary tasks before you do the copy/paste (Format menu, uncheck Summary Tasks)
- If the **Number1** or **Duration1** field change, manually update the **Duration** field again (do the copy/paste steps again)

**Update:** To change ***how*** the Gantt bars are shown, right-click in the Gantt chart area and select Bar Styles. This brings up the dialog box where you can change the format of the Gantt. For example, you could change or add a bar to be drawn from the **Start1** to **Finish1** dates instead of the Start and Finish dates.